# Flutter nested async fuction does not work properly

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I'm trying to get data from nested collections and documents and create some objects with that data. This should be a function that searches firestore and gets the data of the docs and collections with the matching key. My function does that job more or less but it has no stability. That is because there are too many nested async functions but I could not think of a better way. So what do you guys think i can do about it?

```
void kaydol() async {
List<String> dersler = new List();

QuerySnapshot teachers = await _fireStore.collection("Users").where("userType", isEqualTo: 1).get();
teachers.docs.forEach((element) async {
  String userId = element.id;
  String dersName = await _fireStore.collection("Users").doc(userId).collection("dersler").doc().id.toString();
  dersler.add(dersName);
  dersler.forEach((element) async {
    var teacherDersler = await _fireStore.collection("Users").doc(userId).collection("dersler")
        .where("derskodu", isEqualTo: ders.key).get();
    teacherDersler.docs.forEach((element) async {
      if(element.exists){
        await ders.setName(element.id.toString());
      }
    });
    print(ders.getName());
    var quizler =  await _fireStore.collection("Users").doc(userId).collection("dersler")
        .doc(ders.getName()).collection("quizler").get();
    quizler.docs.forEach((element) async {
      Quiz quiz = new Quiz();
      quiz.quizName = element.id;
      quiz.time = element.get("zaman");
      var dbQuestions = await _fireStore.collection("Users").doc(userId).collection("dersler")
          .doc(ders.getName()).collection("quizler").doc(element.id).collection("sorular").get();
      dbQuestions.docs.forEach((dbQuestion) {
        Question q = new Question();
        q.question = dbQuestion.get("question");
        q.answer = dbQuestion.get("dogruCevap");

        q.options.clear();
        List qOptions = dbQuestion.get("cevaplar");
        qOptions.forEach((qOption) {
          q.options.add(qOption.toString());
        });//for each option
        quiz.addQuestion(q);
      });//for each question
      ders.quizList.add(quiz);
    });//for each quiz
  });//for each class
});//for each teacher
```

}}

I get the following error message

```
I/flutter ( 5275): 
E/flutter ( 5275): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(213)] Unhandled Exception: 
'package:cloud_firestore/src/collection_reference.dart': Failed assertion: line 58 pos 14: 
'path.isNotEmpty': a document path must be a non-empty string
E/flutter ( 5275): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core- 
patch/errors_patch.dart:46:39)
E/flutter ( 5275): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5)
E/flutter ( 5275): #2      CollectionReference.doc 
(package:cloud_firestore/src/collection_reference.dart:58:14)
E/flutter ( 5275): #3      _DerseKaydolState.kaydol.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> 
(package:untitled1/quiz_app/derse_kaydol.dart:119:14)
E/flutter ( 5275): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: do not use `forEach` with `async` callback - use "normal" `for (var f in too)` instead

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: ask google for `foreach async await`